# How to rotate hats?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2014

I've seen [many people](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1783619/bradleydotnet) with [rotated hats](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3124333/siking) (i.e. presented at certain angle). How to achieve this?

I've tried to manipulate with mouse on current hat, but I see only drag cursor and I can only move or drag my hat or I can resize it, if I reach borders of my photo. Clicking right mouse on either current hat or on any of received hats doesn't bring anything around rotation.

Am I that blind? Where is the `Rotate Hat` button?

Comment: Agree, that this is a duplicate, but... for the sake of God... beside saying-nothing title and a question about previous year Bash, the correct answer is a one-line update to an answer given a year ago. Must admit, that it would be hard to find it using search...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you are on the hat window on your profile, select "show controls". Then you'll see controls which you can use to rotate, resize and move your hat.

[image: Controls for hats]

Comment: Thanks for a perfect answer. Waiting ("_You can accept an answer in 8 minutes_")...

Answer (score 4):

[image]

And *that's* how you do it.

Comment: +1 for the animation, but -0.5 for the lack of freehand circles. I'll round up this time.

Answer (score 2):

Check the *show controls* box when you are selecting a hat:

[image: show controls]

Two controls appear; one for moving the image (on the right), and one for rotating and sizing (at the top):

[image: controls shown]

Drag the top control closer to the hat to size, left and right to rotate:

[image: rotated boat]

Comment: Martijn, thanks as well. BTW: You've answered to a question being marked as duplicate! :> That isn't something you do to often, am I right? :>

Comment: Nope, but I had put in the effort this time.